# Making a bootstrap panel drop and draggable

Tags: jquery

I need help to make a bootstrap panel drop and draggable using jquery ui. I was wondering if anyone would help me.

Code:

```
     $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: true, snap: 'inner'});
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var one = $(this).html();
    var two = ui.draggable.html();
    $(this).html(two);
    ui.draggable.html(one);
  }
});
```

HTML Class:

```
<div class="pnlOp draggable droppable">
```

Comment: can u send a plunker ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: i made a jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1g5kppaa/1/

Answer (score 2):

Create two divs like so:

```
 <div class="draggable">Draggable</div>
 <div class="droppable">Droppable</div>
```

jQuery...

```
            $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: true, snap: 'inner'});
                $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
                  drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    var one = $(this).html();
                    var two = ui.draggable.html();
                    $(this).html(two);
                    ui.draggable.html(one);
                    $( ".droppable" ).css('background-color','yellow');
                    $( ".draggable" ).css('background-color','pink');
                  }
                });
```

Here is a live preview from jsbin:
https://output.jsbin.com/sericabara

Comment: sorry saw ur jsfiddel link too late.